# How do I limit the number of records shown in an XML feed in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I'm trying to limit the number of records from an XML feed that are passed through to an asp.net repeater.

There are hundreds of "records" and I want to limit the repeater to 4.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

My code behind:

```
    protected void XMLsource()
{
    string URLString = "http://ExternalSite.com/xmlfeed.asp";

    XmlDataSource x = new XmlDataSource();
    x.DataFile = URLString;
    x.XPath = String.Format(@"root/mainNode");

    xPathRepeater.DataSource = x;
    xPathRepeater.DataBind();
}
```

And my front-end code:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="xPathRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <h1><%#XPath ("title") %></h1>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
xPathRepeater.DataSource = x.Data.Take(4);
xPathRepeater.DataBind();
```

Comment: For some reason this actually didn't work. Probably something on my end. The page rendered, but came up empty. Thanks!

Comment: This binds the `Repeater` to a list of strings ... should work ... make sure the code in the `Repeater` binds properly ...

Comment: `<h1><%# Container.DataItem %></h1>`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```
x.XPath = String.Format(@"root/mainNode [position() < 5]");
```